# Variance of conditional geometric random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance

> Given a coin which comes up Heads with probability $p$, let $N_p$ denote the number of times the coin is tossed until the first Heads. Argue that $$N_p = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{with probability } p\\ 1+\tilde{N}_p & \text{with probability } 1-p \end{cases}$$
> where $\tilde{N}_p$ is an independent random variable with the same distribution as $N_p$.
> Using this, show that $\mathbb{E}[N_p] = 1/p$. Also use a similar argument to find $Var(N_p)$.

I find the expectation fairly straightforward:
By rule of iterated expressions, we have:
$$E[E[N_p|\tilde{N_p}]] = E[N_p] = E[p\times 1 + (1-p)\times (1+\tilde{N_p})]$$
$$= p\times p + (1-p) +  (1-p)\times E[\tilde{N_p}] = 1 + \tfrac 1p - 1 = \tfrac 1p$$
However, I am having trouble with finding $V(N_p)$. There is an identity where
$$V(N_p) = E[V(N_p|\tilde{N_p})] + V(E[N_p|\tilde{N_p}])$$
but I do not know how to handle $V(N_p|\tilde{N_p})$. By definition this should be
$$V(Y|X=x)=\sum_{x\in X}(y-E(Y|X=x)^2P(Y|X=x)$$
What is little $y$ here? Is it simply $1$ and $1+N_p$? What does $E(Y|X=x)$ look like? This is a *number*, whereas $E(Y|X)$ is a random variable whose actualizations is $E(Y|X=x)$, but I am not sure what these actualizations look like.How do I find $V(Y|X)$ with $V(Y|X=x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should condition on the outcome of the first toss (call this $Y$), not on $\tilde{N}_p$. Then,

$$V\left(N_p\,|\,Y\right) = \left\{
\begin{array}{c c}
0 & Y=1\\
V\left(N_p\right) & Y=0
\end{array}
\right.$$

and, similarly,

$$\mathbb{E}\left(N_p\,|\,Y\right) = \left\{
\begin{array}{c c}
1 & Y=1\\
1+\mathbb{E}\left(N_p\right) & Y=0
\end{array}
\right.$$

Combining these (and having solved for $\mathbb{E}\left(N_p\right)$ before) should give you an equation that has $V\left(N_p\right)$ on both sides, but you can rearrange terms and solve for it.

Comment: So I should get something like $V(N_p)=E[V(N_p)]$ for $Y = 0$ and $V(N_p) = 0$ for $Y=1$?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, since $V$ of anything is a _constant_, so it cannot depend on the value of $Y$. Use the identity $V\left(N\right) = E\left(V\left(N|Y\right)\right) + V\left(E\left(N|Y\right)\right)$. Both terms are constants. For example, in the first term, you are taking $E$ of a random variable $V\left(N|Y\right)$ which is a function of $Y$, but the randomness due to $Y$ is being "integrated" out due to the expectation.

Comment: I see, so doing this I should get $V(N_p)=V(N_p)(1-p) +(1-\tfrac 1p)^2p+(1-p)$

Comment: Not sure about the last term, since $E\left(N_p|Y\right) = 1 + \left(E\left(N_p\right)\right)\cdot1_{\left\{Y=0\right\}}$. Adding $1$ does not change the variance, so you should get $\left(E\left(N_p\right)\right)^2 p\left(1-p\right)$.

Comment: Your logic makes sense, but I am curious where I failed when solving for: $V(E[N_p|X]) = (1-E[E[N_p|X]])^2p+(1+E[N_p]-E[E[N_p|X]])^2(1-p) = (1-\tfrac 1p)^2p+(1-p)$. What am I misunderstanding in this calculation? Thank you for the extended help by the way.

Comment: You should be computing the variance of a (conditional) expectation, not an expectation of a variance. The weighted sum with weights of $p$ and $1-p$ seems to indicate that you are trying to take an expected value of something.

Comment: But variance is simply expectation of the deviation from the mean no? $E[(x-\mu (x))^2]$

Comment: That's true -- might want to work everything out and see if it simplifies to my expression. I think using the properties of variance is easier though.